# dplyr generate full set of dummy interaction terms for two factor variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, forcats

Let's say I have a two factor variables, one which in my case has many factors (`multi.factor`), and one which has only two factors (`two.factor`), and is itself a dummy.

```r
df <- data.frame(two.factor = rep(c(0,1), 4)) %>%
  mutate(multi.factor = ceiling(row_number()/2))

df

#>   two.factor multi.factor
#> 1          0            1
#> 2          1            1
#> 3          0            2
#> 4          1            2
#> 5          0            3
#> 6          1            3
#> 7          0            4
#> 8          1            4
```

How could I use a `dplyr` or other `tidyverse` method to create a set of dummy interaction terms for these two variables? In other words, I need 4 * 1 = 4 new dummy variables which are 1 if `two.factor` is 1 and `multi.factor` is the factor named in the interaction term, else 0. A long way to do this would be:

```r
df %<>%
  mutate(interact.1 = case_when(multi.factor == 1 & two.factor == 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  mutate(interact.2 = case_when(multi.factor == 2 & two.factor == 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  mutate(interact.3 = case_when(multi.factor == 3 & two.factor == 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  mutate(interact.4 = case_when(multi.factor == 4 & two.factor == 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))

df
#>   two.factor multi.factor interact.1 interact.2 interact.3 interact.4
#> 1          0            1          0          0          0          0
#> 2          1            1          1          0          0          0
#> 3          0            2          0          0          0          0
#> 4          1            2          0          1          0          0
#> 5          0            3          0          0          0          0
#> 6          1            3          0          0          1          0
#> 7          0            4          0          0          0          0
#> 8          1            4          0          0          0          1
```

(I haven't made `multi.factor` or `two.factor` actual factors yet, and I'm just using integers to represent the factor levels to keep replication simple. In my actual data, `multi.factor` are strings. I suspect a `tidyverse` solution won't care.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `multi.factor` is a factor, you can use `map` to create a new column for each level:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(two.factor = rep(c(0,1), 4)) %>%
  mutate(multi.factor = as.factor(ceiling(row_number()/2)))

df %>% 
  bind_cols(
    map( levels(df$multi.factor),
         function(x)
           df %>% transmute(!!paste0("interact.",x) := (multi.factor == x) * two.factor)
    )
  )
```